# mysql calculate percentage for diffrent groups

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to calculate percentage for test groups.
I have group A,B and C. And I want to know how much success percentage each group have.

My first query is counting total test ran in each group by doing the following:
`SELECT type, count(type) as total_runs
From mytable
Where ran_at > '2015-09-11'
Group by type`

Second query is counting success for each group:
`SELECT type, count(type) as success
FROM mytable
where run_status like '%success%' and ran_at> '2015-09-11'
Group by type`

Now I need to divide one in the other and multiply in 100.
how do I do this in one query in an efficient way, I guess nested query is not so efficient- but anyway I can't see how I can uses nested query to solve it.

**I would appreciate answer which include simple way, maybe not so efficient, and an efficient way with explanations**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT type, sum(run_status like '%success%') as success,
       100 * avg(run_status like '%success%') as p_success
FROM mytable
where ran_at> '2015-09-11'
Group by type;
```

In a numeric context, MySQL treats boolean expressions as integers with 1 for true and 0 for false.  The above works assuming that `run_status` is not `NULL`.  If it can be `NULL`, then you need an explicit `case` statement for the `avg()`.

Comment: Can you explain the machanism AVG, does it take all the run statuses and sum them and then take only the ones who has success and divide them?

Comment: @JavaSa . . . I thought I did explain the mechanism.  The boolean is treated as 1 or 0 and he average is he value you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I had this one, but Gordon have a better solution if run_status is not `NULL`.

```
Select type, sum(if(run_status like '%success%',1,0)) / count(1) * 100) as p_success
From mytable
Where ran_at > '2015-09-11'
Group by type
```